# jQuery Datatable: footer and header does not scroll horizontally with table

Tags: datatables

I have used the vertical scroll of datatable to make footer and header visible to the user:

```
$('table').DataTable({
                "scrollY": "50vh",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": false
            });
```

it works fine when the table is small, but when I have used a lot of columns I faced a problem when I try to scroll vertically :
[image]
The header and footer doesn't scroll with the table !!
Any solution to fix this ?

Comment: When you use "scrollY" the header and body are separated in 2 divs with separate tables and so the horizontal scroll doesn't work. Try setting the option "scrollX" to true - `scrollX: true`

Comment: Hi @SlimentTN, hope [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41587/scrolly-misaligned-table-headers-with-bootstrap#Comment_108414) will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @Shashank OMG worked like a charm, you can add it as an answer and I will accept it, thanks a lot :).

Comment: @yash sorry `scrollX: true` is the correct answer, now the footer and header scroll horizontally with the table. I did however used `datatable.columns.adjust().draw();` to adjust my columns but it's not the answer to this specific question. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If your table is in div with overflow:

```
        $("#tableWithOverflow").on('scroll', function () {
           $(".fixedHeader-floating").css("left", "-" + $(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `"scrollX": true`:

```
$('table').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "50vh",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false
            "scrollX": true
        });
```